# rails4 eager loading over 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

I'm not sure if I'm using properly the rails eager loading.

I'd like to call `post.user.profile.first_name` in the view which will be simply `post.user.name` thanks to delegation. I wanna do it with one query, so profile should be loaded along with user on the first query. I'm not sure if I'm doing it well.

Is this the way to go?

profile.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

user.rb

```
has_one :profile
delegate :first_name, .... , to: :profile, allow_nil: true
has_many :posts
```

post.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_one :user_profile, through: :user, source: :profile
```

posts_controller

```
Post.includes(:user, :user_profile).paginate.......
```

Comment: Try it and see. The log file will tell you what queries are being run.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Post.joins(user: :profile).includes(user: :profile).paginate
```

The `joins` is to ensure an inner join for an efficient and accurate query. The `includes` is for the eager load, as you know.

Comment: Peter, so according to you I should not use `has_one :user_profile` in the post model?